# Regex: Using lookahead assertion to check if character exist at most a certain number of times

Tags: python, regex

How do I use lookahead assertion to determine if a certain character exist at most a certain number of times in a string.

For example, let's say I want to check a string that has at least one character to make sure that it contains "@" at most 2 times.  Thanks in advance.  Using python if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, for example:

```
/^(?=([^@]*@){,2}[^@]*$)./
```

Comment: Thanks! How does your answer differ from this: (?=[^@]*[@]{,2}[^@]*$)

Comment: @teggy: In your version, the quantifier `{,2}` applies only to the immediately preceding atom, `[@]`, so it will match `xx@@xx` but not `xx@xx@xx`.

Comment: not working. I am using JavaScript. text = 'aa@@';
regex = /^(?=([^@]*@){,2}[^@]*$)./
console.log(text.match(regex));

Comment: @dorelal: This is a question for Python not Javascript. For Javascript you need to write {0,2} instead of {,2}.

Answer (score 0):

Using a negative lookahead assertion, you can make sure that @ doesn't occur three times:

```
(?!.*@.*@.*@.*).*
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Mark's answer wont quite work as you need to exclude the @ from being matched at other times. Try this:

`^(?=(([^@]*@){0,2}[^@]*$))`

Edit:
Mark fixed his answer, ours should be the same now. Also, fixed.

Comment: Your lookahead should be anchored like Mark's.

Comment: not working. I am using JavaScript. text = 'aa@@';
regex = /^(?=(([^@]*@){,2}[^@]*$))/
console.log(text.match(regex));